# Determining CPU frequency based on application use cases

Tags: arm, cpu-usage, clock, use-case, audiovideoplayback

I do understand the term CPU load. It is an indication of how well is the CPU occupied doing useful tasks. I would periodically measure the amount of time CPU executed the lowest priritized task (such as an Idle task) and that would tell me how loaded the CPU was.

I have often in the past seen system software architects being able to determine the CPU bandwidth requirements of an application.

For example, it would be stated that an audio codec needed 130Mhz for its operation ( while the CPU itself would run at e.g 260Mhz).

Sometimes the requirement would be stated as a program needing only a certain percentage (e.g. 10%) of CPU. In other words, if the CPU ticked at 260Mhz, the program in question would only need 26Mhz.

What is the philosophy/technique to determine computing requirements such as above?